# How to schedule python web jobs on azure

Tags: python, azure, azure-webjobs

I have python project which has main python file `start.py` and `run.cmd`. `run.cmd` file contains the path of the python on azure web app which is below:

```
D:\home\Python364x64\python.exe start.py
```

I created a webjob on `azure` and with type as `Triggered` and triggers as `schedule`. Cron expression I set is `0 */5 * * * *` so that it runs every 5 mins for testing purpose. It was getting executed every 5 mins.

Now I have change the cron expression to `0 0 1 * * *` so that it runs every `1AM` but the problem is it is not getting executed and the logs always says `never ran`. Can anyone please correct me if  I have set the wrong `cron expression` because for every 5mins it was working but for every 1AM daily its not working. Please help. Thanks

Comment: @JayGong can you explain what does ? at the end means.

Comment: @JayGong with `0 0 1 * * ?` it says not a valid cron expression.

Comment: My mistake, your expression is totally correct.(http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2015/06/scheduling-azure-webjobs/#.W6xyS2gzaUk) Another check point is time zones setting, please refer to this doc:https://www.urbzcodes.com/scheduled-tasks-in-the-cloud-with-azures-webjobs-and-timertriggers/ and check the `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` settings.

Comment: I agree with timezone settings, but if it is any timezone, it will hit the specified time in cron and web job should run.

Comment: you did not see any log during a long time,right?

Comment: No. It did not showed any logs because the application/webjob never ran.

Comment: @SAndrew try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240122/how-to-debug-why-azure-web-job-does-not-start)