# Need advice on how to incorporate Python into an Azure, specifically an ASP.NET web application environment

Tags: python, azure

Need advice on how to incorporate Python into an Azure ASP.NET web application environment. Please excuse this question but I am new to Azure and I'm not clear on how to proceed. Every option that I look into looks promising but they all seem to have their own issues. Below is a more thorough explanation but the deal is that I have an Azure account with all kinds of goodies, a full fledged ASP.NET (C#) web app running via App Service, I am new to Azure (but not Python), and I'm hoping to add Python functionality to this whole setup. In short:

- I want to add Python to this setup mainly to run scheduled jobs and also to trigger Python code from ASP.NET web form submissions
- ideally I want a solution that resembles a non-cloud setup. I know this sounds silly but I'm finding the cloud/Azure functionality to be nuanced and not straightforward. I want a place to put a bunch of Python scripts, run, edit, schedule and trigger them from ASP.NET

  - for example: I created a WebJob that runs manually and from the documentation it wasn't clear how it should be called. I just figured out that you need to POST with Basic Auth (and the credentials provided).
  - !Also, Azure CMD does NOT like files with 'underscore _' in them! You cannot submit a Web Job with a py file with an underscore nor can you write output with a file with an underscore
  - !Also, I don't see an option for this Web Job to run Python 3.6.4 (which I installed via extension). Right now it is using 2.7.15...
  - !Also, CRON expression in Azure has six *, not five plus a command. Again, more weird stuff to worry about
  - I tried [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service?view=vs-2017) but the updates to the web page's Web.config file breaks the ASP.NET web pages
- ideally the most cost effective option

Any info is greatly appreciated


**MORE DETAILED EXPLANATION**
Currently I have an ASP.NET site running via Azure App Service and I would like to add Python scripts and possibly Flask/Rest functionality. Note that I am not expecting to serve any content via Python and will largely be running Python scripts either on a scheduled basis or call them from ASP.NET. As a matter of fact, and this is an important point, I'm hoping to have ASP.NET trigger/run a Python script when a web form is submitted. I realize that I could get a similar effect if I make a web call to a Rest api that is running Python. In any event, I can't tell if I should:

- add a Python extension to the current App Service running the web page (I tried this) OR

  - I did install Python 3.6.4 and some packages via pip
  - [These instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service?view=vs-2017) were useful, however the updates to the web page's Web.config file breaks the ASP.NET web pages
- set up a VM that will have all of the Python code (but how can I have the .NET web page(s) call the Python in the VM?) OR
- use Azure functions (I'm completely new to this and must admit that I prefer to have my old school Python environment instead although I see the benefit of using functions. But how do you deal with logging and debugging?)
- or what about a custom windows container (Docker)?

  - This requires installing VS Code and that is OK but I'm looking for a solution that another user can get into with as few interruptions as possible

The idea is to ramp up the use of Python although, like I said, I don't expect Python to be serving any of the web content. It will be used to run in the background and to run scheduled jobs. What is the most robust and hopefully easiest way to add Python functionality to Azure (most importantly in a way to be able to trigger/use Python from an App Service running .NET?)? I've searched online and stack overflow so far with interesting finds but nothing to my liking.

- For example, the following link discusses how to schedule WebJobs. I just created a manual one and when I called the webhook I got the message: "No route registered for '/api/triggeredwebjobs/TestPython/run'" [How to schedule python web jobs on azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52528426/how-to-schedule-python-web-jobs-on-azure)
- The Docker method looks very promising, however, I'm looking for a simple solution as there is another person who will be involved in all of this and he's busy with other projects

  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, though I'm open to more info. Like I mentioned in my post, I used the 'add extension' tool to add Python 3.6.4 to my Azure (installed in D:\home\python364x64).

Then I installed a bunch of packages via pip, these installed into  D:\home\python364x64\Lib\site-packages.

I created a Python folder in webpages\Python where I put my scripts.

Finally, in ASP.NET I used the Diagnostics.Process call to run my code in ~\webpages\Python\somecode_2.py

The main issue is that Azure came with Python 2.7.15 installed. And for some reason when my Python code got executed it was using 3.4 (where that version came from beats me). So for each script, I had to create an `_2.py` version where I simply did the following in order to call the original script via Python 3.6.4. Looks a little nasty but it works. So like I said, I would welcome more info for ways to do this better...

--

```
import os<br>
os.system("D:\\home\python364x64\python.exe SomePython.py {0}".format(add arguments here)
```